# Get Community Translations function in Custom Translator

Tags: microsoft-translator

I can't find such function in the Custom Translator portal. Will be be introduced sometime later next year or this "Get Community Translations" function currently available in MS Hub won't be supported in V3 anymore?

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

It won't be supported in [V3 of the Microsoft Translator Text API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference). Custom Translator includes the [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/custom-translator/what-is-dictionary) functionality that may the closest option.